# Как отключить fail-save в pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Я хочу что бы курсор дёргался по экрану, но когда он касается угол экрана программа выключается. Я пробовал писать: pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False, но она так же касанием угла выключалась.

```
from pyautogui import *
import random
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
for im in range(10):
    move = random.randint(-200,  200)
    moveRel(move, 0)
    move = random.randint(-200,  200)
    moveRel(0, move)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы импортировали * из pyautogui ,а FAILSAFE присваиваете pyautogui.FAILSAFE.
Надо так:

```
import pyautogui
import random

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

for i in range(20):
    random_position = random.randint(-1000,  1000)
    random_position2 = random.randint(-1000,  1000)
    pyautogui.moveTo(random_position, random_position2)
```